# Unable to save async operation result in an array

Tags: node.js, request

I am calling network requests in a forEach loop, each request returns a new object which I would like to push to an array that is outside the forEach. When it is called after awaiting for the network requests to complete, it returns as empty "[]".

```
return this.get(urlOne, function (error, response) {
  if (response.statusCode === 200) {
    let array = [];
    stores.forEach((store) => {
      this.get(urlTwo, function (error, response) {
        if (response.statusCode === 200) {
          array.push(response.body);
        }
      });
    });
    console.log(array);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess but, stores.forEach contents are async thus console.log(array) is called right after stores.forEach() is calle d(not completed) meaning array is blank.
console.log(array); probably needs to be called when the requests are actually done not right after they are made.

Simplest way to test if this is true is to see the array for every push if you see the array growing with your data there is the problem.

```html
return this.get(urlOne, function (error, response) {
  if (response.statusCode === 200) {
    let array = [];
    stores.forEach((store) => {
      this.get(urlTwo, function (error, response) {
        if (response.statusCode === 200) {
          array.push(response.body);
          console.log(array);
        }
      });
    });

  }
});
```

(EDIT)

```
    if (response.statusCode === 200) 
      array.push(response.body);
    else if(response.statusCode === 204)
      console.log(array);
```

Status code 204 means No Content, if this isn't being sent automatically or an equivalent, you may need to send it manual some how.

Comment: Yes. This makes sense. The issue is then, how would I go about waiting for all requests to complete and pushing each response to the array?

Comment: This approach didn't work, the array is never printed since I never receive a 204 response. I'm not sure you're understanding what the issue is. I call multiple network requests, nested inside another single network request. Each of these network requests responds with a JSON object. I would like to push each object to an array outside the loop where the network requests are made and then print the final array once all requests have been made and the array has been populated.

Comment: Yea that's going to be left up to your implementation.  I did say 204 or an equivalent if they are not being sent, YOU will need to send it. You can set the status code in you JSON, just set it to 204 or something other than 200 so you can tell the difference, between a response that contents array data and a response that doesn't, the response that doesn't means you are at the end of the array thus it is safe to display.